# how to handle server being down when piping curl to grep

Tags: bash, curl, grep, exit-code

I am trying to write a script to query a web server API and check for a value but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to best go about it. So far what I am doing is using curl to get a response and then piping that to grep to look for a pattern. If the pattern exist, I do one thing, if not, I do another.

```
if curl http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/query | grep -q mypattern; then
    echo "success"
    else echo "boo"
fi
```

But if the server is down I don't know how to handle that neatly because the server being down produces the same result as not finding the pattern. What I want to happen is for curl to keep making the request until the server responds and then grep the result. I know I could probably do it but it will be very kludgy. One thought was a loop to curl first until the exit code is 0 but I'm sure there is a more practical way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `$PIPESTATUS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if curl http://192.168.1.2/api/query | grep -q mypattern; then
  echo "Found pattern"
elif [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Server up"
else
  echo "Server down"
fi
```

Comment: I forgot all about the pipestatus array.  Nice one.  I tested this example and it works well - except that the server down state can potentially hang there for a long time if the API server doesn't reject the connection attempt (a potentially "down" scenario) ?

Comment: Aha! I think that is exactly what I was looking for. I did come up with a nice 2 line solution but it involved connecting to the server twice which is less than ideal as without atomicity there is still a chance of error. The pipestatus is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=5              # number of times to try.

testserver(){
    read server mypattern <<<"$@"   # read values of server and pattern
    try=1                           # lets start with try number 1.

    while (( try++ < n )); do       # have tried enough times?
        test="$(curl --max-time 10 "$server" 2>/dev/null)"
        (( $? == 0 )) &&            # If the connection was valid.
        [[ "$test" =~ "$mypattern" ]] && echo "success" && break 1
        sleep 5m                    # wait a little before trying again.
    done
}

testserver "http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/query" "SomeStringToTest"
```

Comment: That works but I forgot that the grep also needs to loop. This script is checking a queue and I need to continually check the queue (with the curl + grep combo) and then do something once the queue is empty/pattern is no longer found.

Comment: @user2328273 Just add an additional wrapper for the values of `server` and `grep string`. Post already edited.

Comment: I seem to have gotten it working with just 2 lines:

    until test=`curl http://192.168.1.2:8080`; do sleep 5m; done

    until !(test2=`curl http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/quey | grep -c mypattern`);do echo $test2 && sleep 5s;done

Comment: @user2328273 That is missing 1.- the max-time of curl (when the server fails to connect) 2.- makes two connections to the server (the connection is not atomic) 3.- Does not count the number of connections (infinite trials) in `test1` 4.- If the curl fails to get the pattern, the command will keep to be tested "ad infinitum" (never stops trying) in `test2`. If all that is ok with you, use it.

Comment: What is `sleep 5m` please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The man sleep say that it is 5 (M)inutes. `sleep NUMBER[SUFFIX]...`  SUFFIX may be `s' for seconds (the default), `m' for minutes, `h' for hours or `d' for days. That is for GNU sleep.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem too kludgy:

```
if while ! curl http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/query; do sleep 1; done | 
    grep -q mypattern; then
    echo "success"
fi
```

you might want to limit the number of time you call curl.  You could do that with something like:

```
i=0; if while test $((i++)) -lt 4 && ! curl ...
```

Comment: This: `i=0; if while ((i++<4)) && ! curl ...` seems equivalent (and more idiomatic).

Answer (score 0):

`curl` has an inbuilt timeout status, with a dedicated exit code (28).

From the documentation:

> ```
> --connect-timeout <seconds>
>               Maximum time in seconds that  you  allow  curl's  connection  to
>               take.   This  only  limits the connection phase, so if curl con-
>               nects within the given period it will continue - if not it  will
>               exit.  Since version 7.32.0, this option accepts decimal values.
>
> .....
>
> 28     Operation  timeout.  The  specified  time-out period was reached
>               according to the conditions.
> ```

So you could script the main loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#mypattern.sh example

query="$1"
mypattern="$2"
dogrep () {

if (grep -q "$mypattern" /tmp/result); 
    then 
        echo "success"
    else
        echo "boo"
fi
}

curl -s --connect-timeout 5 "$query" -o /tmp/result    

curlresult="$?"

case "$curlresult" in
"0") dogrep ; exit ;;
"28") echo "Could not connect to server" ; exit ;;
*) echo "something else went wrong" ; exit ;;
esac
```

- `$1` is the API URL
- `$2` is the pattern

### **Example Results:**

```
bash: >./mypattern.sh "http://google.com" "The document has moved"
success

bash: >./mypattern.sh "http://google.com" "The document has movde"
boo

bash: >./mypattern.sh "http://fjbdjhf" "The document has moved"
something else went wrong

bash: >./mypattern.sh "http://real.server.address.that.is.down" "The document has moved"
Could not connect to server
```

In the above:

- Example 1: Successful connection, and successful pattern match
- Example 2: Successful connection, and no pattern match
- Example 3: Not even a real server, this is the exception case
- Example 4: Real server, but cannot connect, times out in 5 seconds

I'm sure this could be perfected to some degree more to your specific requirements if you tweaked the conditions of the server being down.

- In this example case:
  "**server being down**" means that the host resolves to a real address, and the connection attempt is not otherwise rejected within 5 seconds.

  - If this were an API address on the internet, then a simple ping check to your ISP gateway in there to verify connectivity to the internet in general, plus the 5 second timeout would cover pretty accurately a server being effectively down.
  - **In your case**, being on a LAN, you'll have to work out what exact conditions mean the server is down, but this template breaks up the parts enough to make it simple to accomodate those various factors.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ! CURL_OUT="$(curl http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/query)"; do
    sleep 5
done
if echo "$CURL_OUT" | grep -q mypattern ; then
    echo "success"
else 
    echo "boo"
fi
```